# Commit new file in Bitbucket Cloud generates "We had trouble committing your changes"

Tags: bitbucket, git-commit, bitbucket-cloud

I created a new file in Bitbucket Cloud (using the web interface - bitbucket.org).

I followed the next steps:

- copied & pasted a value as file name
- added a file content
- clicked on Commit
- changed the default commit message
- Commit

and I got the following message:

> We had trouble committing your changes.

[image: Commit changes - trouble]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is this for Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org) or a self-hosted Bitbucket Server?

Comment: It's Bitbucket Cloud. I added the details in my post. Thanks for your clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bitbucket bug.

It happens when you pasted a text using **right click > Paste** and no key was pressed when the cursor what inside the input box.

When you get the message:

> We had trouble committing your changes.

you can see **"Creating on branch"** below (without the file name).

[image: Creating on branch]

When it **works** fine, you will see the **file name** between "Creating" and "on branch".

[image: Creating file on branch]

#### Possible solutions:

- Click in the file name input box and press a key

  - E.g.: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> / <kbd>Shift</kbd> / <kbd>Alt</kbd> / <kbd>Enter</kbd>
  - Not OK: <kbd>Tab</kbd> / <kbd>Esc</kbd>
- Paste again the text by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>
- Type the text instead of pasting it

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm using a VPN browser extension so I figure out that's the issue even when I already add the website to bypass list. So I disable the extension and try restarting my browser and it works fine.